# BufferedImage + jPanel equivalent way to view an image in C++ using Qt

Tags: java, c++, image, qt, user-interface

I have a Java program that used a BufferedImage attached to a jPanel to display some image data that I am reading in from a byte array. I was getting a row of the Image at a time into the byte array, getting the WriteableRaster of the image, and calling the setDataElements() method of the raster, and then setData of the BufferedImage to get the new data in.

What is the equivalent way to do this in C++?

Edit: I have Qt, and thought I might try to build my UI using that

Comment: If you want to do image processing in C++, check-out OpenCV: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [QImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html) is the closest in concept to a BufferedImage.  It has a method [loadFromData()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#loadFromData) which can load image data from an array.  You can then convert that into a [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html) by calling [QPixmap::fromImage()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html#fromImage) and display it in a [QLabel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlabel.html) or whatever.

Comment: I have been able to get my data from unsigned char** into a QPixMap - can you tell me how I am supposed to access the label? I called it "viewLabel" but in my button clicked() slot, I am not able to access MainWidget::viewLabel or anything to be able to call the setPixMap method

Answer (score 5):

C++ doesn't have any UI framework built into its standard library like Java does.  You need to pick one, like GTK, QT, whatever.

Until you do, your question can't be answered because it's going to be different depending.

Comment: Good comment - I added that I have Qt, and I am open to using that to build my UI and display this image